# "Remind me later" functionality for local notifications

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I want to extend my local notifications functionality by adding a "Remind me later" action. In other words, I would like to re-present a notification after a set amount of time if the user taps on the "Remind me later" button.

Even though everything should be wired correctly in my app (checking if notifications are enabled, setting the notification category and delegate, handling remind me later functionality), the notification that is scheduled after tapping on the remind later button does not show at all.

Setting everything up (checking permissions, setting up category)

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) {(accepted, error) in
        if !accepted {
            print("Notification access denied.")
        }
    }

    let action = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "remindLater", title: "Remind me later", options: [])
    let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "myCategory", actions: [action], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([category])

    return true
}
```

Handling tap on "Remind me later"

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    if response.actionIdentifier == "remindLater" {
        let newDate = Date(timeInterval: 10, since: Date())
        scheduleNotification(at: newDate, withCompletionHandler: { 
            completionHandler()
        })
    }
}
```

Actual code which sets up a local notification:

```
func scheduleNotification(at date: Date) {
    let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    let components = calendar.dateComponents(in: .current, from: date)
    let newComponents = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, timeZone: .current, month: components.month, day: components.day, hour: components.hour, minute: components.minute)

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: newComponents, repeats: false)

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Tutorial Reminder"
    content.body = "Just a reminder to read your tutorial over at appcoda.com!"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
    content.categoryIdentifier = "myCategory"

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: date.description, content: content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) {(error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Uh oh! We had an error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? [I am using AppCoda iOS 10 user notifications guide.](http://www.appcoda.com/ios10-user-notifications-guide/) and [this is the sample code](https://github.com/appcoda/NotificationsUI-Demo).

Comment: The problem is that you need to use a unique identifier to every notification you are scheduling. You can use the trigger date description

Comment: Thanks @LeoDabus. Using unique identifiers, such as the trigger date description like you suggested, did not change anything at all. No new notification is presented.

Comment: You need to close your app to receive the notification

Comment: Thanks so much @LeoDabus. Your solution works! Please feel free to post your comment(s) as an answer and I will be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you need to use a unique identifier to every notification you are scheduling. You can use the trigger date description. Don't forget that you need to close your app to receive the notification.